# Posting To Twitter With C# As a Browser Without Using OAuth/API

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I am trying to post updates to twitter accounts like a web browser does. How can I post to twitter like this without using the Twitter API and registering my program? As of right now my code generates a 401 authentication failed error. Here is the code I have at the moment although I have tried other setups previously:

**EDIT:** I fixed it through lots of analysis through fiddler and finding out exactly which headers twitter needed. There were some custom ones I had to create in VS that showed up in fiddler. Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update your twitter status without going through the authentication process, even if you going through the browser you have to still enter the username and password, if you want to simulate the login through a browser, you have to check what values twitter requires for allowing a user to login, you can check this by going through the HTML, and also through the HTML headers using a tool like fiddler. You also have to manage cookies in your code and also have to check what form values twitter needs to update the status

Comment: I can already successfully log in with accounts just not post any updates. I will take a look at fiddler though.

Comment: Do not use "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json" for url, i think this is for Titter API, for normal twitter website you have to use https://twitter.com/sessions?phx=1, check the html for [Twitter Login Page](http://twitter.com/#!/login?_twitter_noscript=1)

Comment: While checking with http live headers when I posted a tweet with firefox it used the json url. I am going to have a look with fiddler in a minute.

Comment: And i think you seriously need to reconsider your approach to use XAUTH for twitter, as the current approach will break your application once twitter changes anything,. [XAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) is a just like oauth but doesn't require you to go through the oauth process

Comment: No the url i posted is for logging in, if you are able to sucessfully login then you may have to check whether you are missing any form values that are being posted by the browser, you also may wnt to set your application user agent to simulate any popular browser, you can find a [list of UserAgents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) easily on the web

Comment: I have tried with a user agent and still received the same error. Also I am willing to update my program when twitter makes changes. I will look into xauth

Comment: Twitter uses the their own APIs as well. You simply have to work via them.